# C# - DatagridView and ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c#, datagridview, items, contextmenustrip

I have a datagridview with five columns and context menu strip which have items and sub items. When I right click on last column I want to open context menu.

I tried this code, but it's open context menu strip without sub items.

```
dataGrid.Columns[dataGrid.Columns.Count].HeaderCell.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want to open your ContextMenuStrip if your user right clicks the header of your DataGridView's last column.  I would use the DataGridView `MouseDown` event and in that event check for these conditions and if they're met call the `Show` method of your ContextMenuStrip.

Like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
        var ht = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        // See if the user right-clicked over the header of the last column.
        if ((    ht.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1) 
             && (ht.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.ColumnHeader)) {
            // This positions the menu at the mouse's location.
            contextMenuStrip1.Show(MousePosition);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to attach context menu to **header** of your last column, your direction is probably right. But index of last column is `dataGrid.Columns.Count - 1`. So, this code works fine for me:

```
dataGrid.Columns[dataGrid.Columns.Count - 1].HeaderCell.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1; ?
```

Subitems are in place.